# Angular 2 Performance Issues in Firefox

Tags: .net, angular

I am working on one project, which is in Dot Net Core and Angular 2. But, Every time, while debugging, the application hangs. Is there any solution to improve the performance in firefox?

Comment: Is problem only firefox? Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Yes, on chrome, it's working fine.

Comment: The performance issues are also in IE Edge and IE 11

Comment: I'm working owith opera, firefox and chrome. They working same. Maybe update Firefox. My Firefox verison is 53.0.2 (64-bit) in linux mint.

Comment: hımm maybe windows os issue i use Linux.

Comment: Firefox updated to 53.0.2, but still there is issue